# Get the discounts list by given discount strategies and renew months

Tags: python, math

I have a product names `toy`.

there is a series of discounts for its sale.

customer buy a `toy` a duration, when reach `expire_time` he will renew it.

so the `toy` instance have `pay_time` and `expire_time` fields:

```
class Toy(models.Model):
    pay_time = DateTimeField()
    expire_time = DateTimeField()
```

when a customer have a `toy` instance, the `pay_time` is `2018.01.01`, and `expire_time` is `2018.05.01`. now when time reaches `2018.05.01`, the customer will renew the product.

the renew strategies discounts list are bellow:

```
renew_discounts_list: [
    { 
      discount: 0.20,
      min_mon: 1,
      max_mon:3
    },
    { 
      discount: 0.15,
      min_mon: 4,
      max_mon:6
    },
    ....
]
```

if the customer want to renew `17` months, it is very complex for calculation.

**I want to a results of discounts**, this is my required output:

```
[
    {
        'months': 1,
        'disconts': 0.15  #(4~6: 0.15)
    },
    {
        'months': 3,
        'disconts': 0.10  #(7~9: 0.10)
    }, 
    .... 

]
```

the results' total `months` is `17`.

I tried use judge for the solution, but its not a good solutions for it.

Comment: It is not clear what your input and desired output are. Also, should the discounts somehow add up or is only the last discount valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recursion for the calculation:

I assume the `toy` instance to a dict:

```
toy = {
    'pay_time': 1,  # there I use the count replace of the datetime, you can change by yourself.
    'expire_time': 4
}
```

I list a `discounts` strategies list:

```
discounts = [

    {
        'min_month': 1,
        'max_month': 3,
        'discounts': 0.30
    },
    {
        'min_month': 4,
        'max_month': 6,
        'discounts': 0.25
    },
    {
        'min_month': 7,
        'max_month': 9,
        'discounts': 0.10
    },
    {
        'min_month': 10,
        'max_month': 13,
        'discounts': 0.08
    }

]
```

Use the recursion method:

```
def get_discount_recursion(discounts_list, months):

    expire_months = toy.get('expire_time') - toy.get('pay_time')  

    total_months = months + expire_months

    left_months = 0

    if get_max_month() < total_months:
        disc_months = total_months - get_max_month() + 1
        disc = {
            'months': disc_months,
            'discounts': 0
        }
        left_months = months - disc_months
        discounts_list.append(disc)

    else:
        for item in discounts:
            print('item,' , item, total_months, months)
            if (item.get('min_month') <= total_months and item.get('max_month') >= total_months):

                if item.get('min_month') <= expire_months and item.get('max_month') > expire_months:
                    disc_months = total_months - expire_months + 1
                else:
                    disc_months = total_months - item.get('min_month') + 1

                left_months = months - disc_months

                disc = {
                    'months': disc_months,
                    'discounts': item.get('discounts')
                }
                discounts_list.append(disc)

    if left_months <= 0: return discounts_list
    else: return get_discount_recursion(discounts_list, left_months)


def get_max_month():

    max = 0

    for item in discounts:
        max = item.get('max_month') if item.get('max_month') > max else max

    return max
```

I have tested it:

```
res = get_discount_recursion([], 13)
print(res)
```

output:

```
[{'months': 4, 'discounts': 0}, {'months': 3, 'discounts': 0.08}, {'months': 3, 'discounts': 0.1}, {'months': 3, 'discounts': 0.25}]
```